# Redirect to view on taping push message from notification bar in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I am trying to code a chat app in ios. I need to know how to redirect to any perticular view on taping push message in notification bar if the app is running in background or if the app is killed.

Need response ASAP !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... When the app is not running and a push notification is received, when the user clicks on the push notification, the app is launched and now... the push notification contents will be available in the -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method in it's launchOptions parameter.

In other words... -didReceiveRemoteNotification won't execute this time and you'll also need to do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        //...
        NSDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"];
        NSDictionary *apsInfo = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

        if(apsInfo) {
            //there is some pending push notification, so do something
            //in your case, show the desired viewController in this if block
        }
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks For this, But this one works if the app is launching for the first time.
If the app is running in background and a new push notification come then ?